# Java default number to string behavior

Tags: java, string, format, double

I have two projects in my eclipse workspace which are having similar tasks. Both projects have a special part where I convert a `double` to an `String`.

I both projects I did this by calling `String.valueOf(var)`.

In the older project I get the number always in a format like "-0.00097656" which is the format I need. In the newer one I get an tenth exponential format like "-9.765625E-4". I also have the fact that the old project cuts the string to be small enough.

My question is: Which commands can cause to this behavior that java changes the default conversion output. I already searched the code but I don't see something which does this. Or is it maybe an eclipse option?

I want to get the newer project consistent to the older one and I don't want to use these string format calls every time in the new project. Anywhere in the old project there must be a setting or some calls...

Hope somebody can give a hint.

Comment: Are you sure that you used the same input number in both cases you described? Did the same value of "var" yielded both results: "-0.002341" and "-9.765625E-4" ?

Comment: No not the same number but it should be only an example for the different formats. I will make this more clear.

Answer (score 6):

It's clearly explained in the javadoc (see [`Double.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)) - format depends on magnitude of number:

> - If *m* is greater than or equal to 10<sup>-3</sup> but less than 10<sup>7</sup>, then it is represented as the integer part of m, in decimal form with no leading zeroes, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by one or more decimal digits representing the fractional part of *m*.
> - If *m* is less than 10<sup>-3</sup> or greater than or equal to 10<sup>7</sup>, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be the unique integer such that 10<sup>n</sup> <= *m* < 10<sup>n+1</sup>; then let a be the mathematically exact quotient of m and 10<sup>n</sup> so that 1 <= *a* < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of *a*, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of *a*, followed by the letter 'E' ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of *n* as a decimal integer, as produced by the method `Integer.toString(int)`.

If you want a specific format, use [`String.format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) or something similar.

Comment: Thats rather an explaination of why this happens not a solution for the problem.

Comment: Yes but it seems that this behavior was "overloaded" in the old project and I want to get this in the new one also. I have used exactly the same input and got two different formats as output in the two projects. The question is: What can cause this?

Comment: @fpdragon: Are you sure you get them with `String.valueOf()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try [String.format()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). And have a look at the [Format String Syntax](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). This should help to get your doule into the format you want it.

```
String.format("%1$f",var);
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I already have tried this and it works but the question is why is there a difference between these projects? Anyway +1

Comment: `String.format("%1$f",var)` rounds to the 6th digit. That won't work

Comment: Okay that was just a quick look at the formatting Syntax i'm pretty sure there's a way to do this with it.

Comment: yes, i showed in the answer you need smth like `%.10f` where the number (10) represents the required figures. However then it pads zeros at the end (so they have to cut off)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `digits` is applied to the format precision, and you can have it a constant, if need be.

```
public static String formatDouble(double d, int digits){
    String s = String.format(Locale.US, "%."+digits+"f", d);
    if (s.indexOf('.')<0)
        return s;

    int last = s.length();                  
    while (s.charAt(--last)=='0');
    return s.substring(0,last+1);       
}
```